# the name of the game is TicTacToe

Tags: java

This is a tic tac toe game that I wrote myself.

I need help breaking down this code such as identifying the methods that I used, etc. For example, I know that I used multiple 2D arrays, but I am just having trouble explaining this code to somebody.

Can you point out what I should do differently to make this code more readable?

Anything would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and I am looking forward to hearing what the codereview.stackexchange community has to say about my game.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe //Name of the game
{

public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{

final int Size = 3;
char[][] board = new char[Size][Size]; // This is the game board

resetBoard(board); // Initializes the board. (' ' for all spots)

System.out.println("Let's play Tic Tac Toe!"); //Introduces game to the 
player
showBoard(board);

System.out.print("Which symbol do you want to play as, 'x' or 'o'?"); //Game 
asks what symbol player wants
char playerSymbol = sc.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
char compSymbol = (playerSymbol == 'x') ? 'o' : 'x';

System.out.println();
System.out.print("Do you want to go first, yes or no? "); //Game asks player 
if they wants to go first
char ans = sc.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

int turn; // 0 is the player, 1 is the computer
int remainCount = Size * Size;

if(ans == 'y') // First move of the game
{
turn = 0;
playerChoice(board, playerSymbol); // Player makes their first move

}

else {

turn = 1;
compChoice(board, compSymbol); // Computer makes their first move

}

showBoard(board);
remainCount--;

// Game is played until someone wins
boolean done = false; 
int winner = -1; // 0 is the player, 1 is the computer, -1 is a draw

while(!done && remainCount > 0) {

done = isGameWon(board, turn, playerSymbol, compSymbol); //Has somebody one?

if(done) 
  winner = turn;
 else {

 // Nobody has won yet. Continue playing the game.
 turn = (turn + 1 ) % 2;

 if (turn == 0)
      playerChoice(board, playerSymbol);
    else
      compChoice(board, compSymbol); 

   // Shows the board after one move  
   showBoard(board);
    remainCount--;
  }
  }


  if (winner == 0)
  System.out.println("You Win!"); //Player is declared the winner
  else if (winner == 1)
  System.out.println("You Lost!"); //Computer is declared the winner
  else
  System.out.println("Tie!"); //The game ends in a tie 

  }

 public static void resetBoard(char[][] brd)
 {
 for (int i = 0; i < brd.length; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < brd[0].length; j++)
    brd[i][j] = ' ';
}  

public static void showBoard(char[][] brd)
{
int numRow = brd.length;
int numCol = brd[0].length;

System.out.println();

// Column header
System.out.print("    ");
for (int i = 0; i < numCol; i++)
  System.out.print(i + "   ");
System.out.print(' ');

System.out.println(); // Blank line after the header

// Table header
for (int i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
  System.out.print(i + "  ");
  for (int j = 0; j < numCol; j++) {
    if (j != 0)
      System.out.print("|");
    System.out.print(" " + brd[i][j] + " ");
  }

  System.out.println();

  // Seperator line
  if (i != (numRow - 1)) {

  System.out.print("   ");
    for (int j = 0; j < numCol; j++) {
      if (j != 0)
        System.out.print("+");
      System.out.print("---");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
System.out.println();

}

public static void playerChoice(char[][] brd, char psym)
{
System.out.print("Enter the row and column: ");
int rowIndex = sc.nextInt();
int colIndex = sc.nextInt();


while (brd[rowIndex][colIndex] != ' ') {
  System.out.print("That spot is already taken. Try again. Enter the row and 
column: ");
  rowIndex = sc.nextInt();
  colIndex = sc.nextInt();
}

brd[rowIndex][colIndex] = psym;
}

 public static void compChoice(char[][] brd, char csym)
{

// Finds the first empty spot and makes a mark there
for (int i = 0; i < brd.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < brd[0].length; j++) {
    if (brd[i][j] == ' ') { // Empty spot
      brd[i][j] = csym;
      return;
    }
    }
    }
    }

 public static boolean isGameWon(char[][] brd, int turn, char psym, char csym)
 {
char sym;
if (turn == 0)
  sym = psym;
else
  sym = csym;

int i;
int j;
boolean win = false;

 // Checks win by row
 for (i = 0; i < brd.length && !win; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < brd[0].length; j++) {
    if (brd[i][j] != sym)
      break;
  }
  if (j == brd[0].length)
    win = true;
  }

 // Checks win by column  
 for (j = 0; j < brd[0].length && !win; j++) {
   for (i = 0; i < brd.length; i++) {
     if (brd[i][j] != sym)
      break;
  }
  if (i == brd.length)
    win = true;
}

 // Checks win by diagonal (1)
 if (!win) {
  for (i = 0; i < brd.length; i++) {
    if (brd[i][i] != sym)
      break;
  }
  if (i == brd.length)
    win = true;
}

// Checks win by diagonal (2)
if (!win) {
  for (i = 0; i < brd.length; i++) {
    if (brd[i][brd.length - 1 - i] != sym)
      break;
  }
  if (i == brd.length)
    win = true;
}

// Return win
return win;
}
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking an explanation of code (whether your own code or someone else's code) are off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: We could reopen the question if you rephrase the question to ask for suggestions for improvements, rather than for an explanation of code. Note, though, that you also need to correct the code: some of the `// comments`, for example, span more than one line, thus making the code syntactically invalid.

Comment: The current question: "**I** wan't to be able to explain this (*my*) code to somebody else" seems to me like it's in a gray zone. @John Deer seems to have interpreted this like you suggested as well and shows how to improve the code readability making it easier to explain it to someone else. (Thus answering the original question by doing a normal code review). I do agree that the wording of this question could be done a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot to see and learn here.  Rather than point out every line, what I'm going to suggest to you is to try to explain each part of the logic to yourself.  What I want you to do is look at a small section of the code that does something, state clearly in just a few words what the intent of that piece of code is, and then *turn that little block of code into a new method.*

Let's run through a small example.  I see these lines

```
System.out.print("Which symbol do you want to play as, 'x' or 'o'?"); //Game 
asks what symbol player wants
char playerSymbol = sc.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
char compSymbol = (playerSymbol == 'x') ? 'o' : 'x';
```

It seems that the intent is to ask what symbol the player wants.  Let's move this into its own method:

```
public char getPlayerSymbol()
{
    System.out.print("Which symbol do you want to play as, 'x' or 'o'?");
    return sc.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
}
```

Back in the main method, we replace the existing code with a call to our new method.

```
char playerSymbol = getPlayerSymbol();
char compSymbol = (playerSymbol == 'x') ? 'o' : 'x';
```

The logic behind the compSymbol assignment is kind of ugly - let's do the same thing there.

```
public char getOpponentSymbol(char symbolIn)
{
    return (symbolIn == 'x') ? 'o' : 'x';
}
```

And this is what remains in our main method:

```
char playerSymbol = getPlayerSymbol();
char compSymbol = getOpponentSymbol(playerSymbol);
```

Now, the main method just got a little bit simpler, and a whole lot clearer.  The function's purposes became clear in their names alone.  This lets us remove the comment, and that's a good thing because names are far more important to readability than comments.

It's also exposed our first bug.  What if the player picks 'j'?  Do we really want to let a player pick something other than X or O, if that would violate the rules of the game?  So maybe the routine needs a bit of input validation to ensure the rules are followed.  We should probably write a `bool ValidateSymbol(char symbolIn)` method to solve this problem (I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.)

This activity even has a formal name: *[Refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)*.  This technique is called *Extract Method*.  There is a bit more to the refactoring process, but it's all focused on improving the architecture and readability of your code.  Once you learn how to do this, you'll be on the next level of improving your coding skills.  I'm not going to go through all the rest of the code, as this is a task you must learn to master for yourself.  Once you've done this, come back and ask us for another review.  I'm sure there's more we can help you learn.

Comment: You have a very good answer for such a broad question. Nice job